# Is there anything in the TFS API that would allow me to retrieve multiple Changeset details through a single API call?

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm using the TFS API (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client) to build a C# tool to make querying for some stuff a bit easier. I'm running into an issue with performance in retrieving changesets.

I have a list of changeset IDs (a few thousands) and I need to retrieve the user's display name (or ID, that would work too) for each one of them. The only way I've been able to figure out for doing this is to use VersionControlServer, which exposes a GetChangeset method. This allows me to retrieve a single changeset at a time, and for the amount of changesets I'm attempting to query, it takes way too long.

I've been trying to figure out a way to retrieve a batch of Changesets at once, but no luck. QueryHistory won't really help either, as the changesets aren't consecutive. I've tried retrieving the Changesets as artifacts using the linking service, but as expected the artifacts don't contain much more than the URI for the changesets.

Is there any way that anyone knows of to get the details of multiple changesets as a batch without having to do call GetChangeset over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the REST API of [By a list of IDs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#by-a-list-of-ids), which retrieves representations for all items given a list of paths:

```
POST https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesetsBatch?api-version=1.0
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changesetIds": [
    1,
    3,
    6,
    1,
    3,
    6
  ],
  "commentLength": 90
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#in-a-range-of-ids) are better for this kind of thing.

Ex: `GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?fromId=2&toId=5&api-version=1.0`

There's a [C# wrapper library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries) if you'd prefer to not deal with making REST calls and dealing with the resulting JSON.

Comment: I have a feeling this may come down to pretty much the same thing in the end. This seems to be the equivalent of using QueryHistory with a from/to changeset ID. Since the IDs I have aren't sequential, I'd still need multiple API calls.